# Install this python package on Github using Conda

Tags: python, github, conda

Pardon my ignorance, I wanted to install the following python package on [see here](https://github.com/microsoft/otdd)
Via Conda. So far, I cloned the repository and haven't had much success. Initially when I tried the command in the terminal:

> conda env create -f environment.yaml

I get the error:

> EnvironmentFileNotFound:

I've tried moving the repository manually into the folder that has the environment name, and then tried:

> conda install .

But got the following error:

> DirectoryNotACondaEnvironmentError: The target directory exists, but it is not a conda environment.

I was looking for some insight on what to do here. I am very new to do this, so I apologize for redundancy.

Comment: Copying into the envs/ folder is a bad idea. Retry the `conda env create` command but make sure to be in the cloned folder first. Or give the full path to the file. That is, this seems like a typo.

Comment: To be in the cloned folder, I just change directory in terminal? Thank you!

Comment: yes, use `cd` to change the current directory. Or give the full path: `conda env create -f folder/environment.yaml`

Comment: I got it! Thank you!